# Split a string with HTML <br> tag into multiline string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a string that contains html break tag to split the string as I would like to split the string into multiple lines but it doesn't seem to render the string as multi-line in UI. How can I achieve the following?

`testString = "This is line one<br>This is line two<br>This is line three"`

Expected Output:

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
```

I read about `dangerouslysettinginnerHTML` but don't want to use it in my code. As far as split is concerned what I did was I tried

```jsx
text.split('<br>').map(each => each + <br>)
```

but that didn't work. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to render the string as multi-line in UI." - what UI? A browser will render separate lines as a single line unless they contain <br> or <p>.

Comment: I understand your problem but but what exactly did you do that didn't work?

Comment: Generally speaking, the easiest way to do this with React is probably use `dangerouslysetinnerHTML`, but that's not a best practice. It's better to use javascript to split the string and then map the results while appending a `br` tag after each output

Comment: Yes I read about dangerouslysettinginnerHTML but don't want to use it in my code. As far as split is concerned what I did was I tried text.split('<br>').map(each => each + <br>)

Comment: Even that didn't work

Comment: A hint for future posts... code belongs in your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this outside of [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is split and [flat-map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the string to an array of JSX elements.

```jsx
{testString
  .split(/<br ?\/?>/)
  .flatMap((line, i) => [line, <br key={`line-${i}`} />])}
```

The regex delimiter is designed to split on any form of `<br>`, `<br/>` or `<br />`.

[image: Edit tender-taussig-uc6y50]